# Sending data our GPS coordinates properly

Tags: android, localization, gps

So basically what my problem is:
I am trying to make some sort of `GPS` app and in it I want to send the coordinates(longitude latitude) of where the user is to a server. It works well so far but I have reached a problem. I want to call my `sendDataToserver()` method periodically (every 5 seconds or so - BTW this is working correctly) method only after coordinates have been received from the `GPS`. But the thing is I cant figure out how to make ...(if statement or something)... the sendDataToserver() method to be called only after the coordinates have been received/changed. I am using an if statement right now:

```
if(lat != 0 && long !=0)
{
   sendDataToserver();
}
```

but ... as you might have guessed 0.0 is a valid coordinate ... So can you give me an idea how to fix this problem so that `sendDataToserver()` could be called every 5 seconds or so and only if coordinates have been received?

Answer (score 0):

First of all sending GPS data again & again to websever is not a good idea. This will dry your battery soon. To avoid this situation you should create a batch of 10-20 points togather in Json kind of format and then send those collected data togather.

Now coming to your GPS point, You need to use [GpsStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.Listener.html). This listener has returns `GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX` when your device finds a GPS point. So you can write a condition that as soon as Gps State Listener returns this value you call your web-service call.

```
final Listener onGpsStatusChange = new GpsStatus.Listener() {

    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(event){
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
        // Started...
        break ;
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
        // First Fix...
        break ;
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
        // Stopped...
        break ;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: this seems possible to work but where should I put this method inside OnCreate or OnLocation changed?

Comment: put this in `onResume()`

Comment: so jut to make sure I am doing everything right:
 case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
        sendDataToserver()
        break ;

Comment: @user3182266 Just putting this code will not work,I think you need to change your coding according to this listener. Then only it will work. see an [example code](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/ujL593Wb4VA)

Answer (score 0):

at first: do not use long as variable Name.

what about saving the last coordinate in a temporary variable like:

```
if(lastLat != newLat && lastLong != newLong) // code goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem:

```
unsigned long GPS_WAIT=5000;
curr_time= millis();
if(curr_time>=GPS_WAIT)
{
sendDataToserver();curr_time=0;
}else
{
curr_time= millis();
}
```